# This not working as expected in nested arrow functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm new to arrow functions and I don't understand why I can use this code:

```
const adder = {
    sum: 0,
    add(numbers) {
        numbers.forEach(n => {
            this.sum += n;
        });
    }
};

adder.add([1,2,3]);
// adder.sum === 6
```

... and it works just fine, but in the following case the `this` is not bound properly:

```
const adder = {
    sum: 0,
    add: (numbers) => {
        numbers.forEach(n => {
            this.sum += n;
        });
    }
};

adder.add([1,2,3]);
// Cannot read property sum
```

Comment: Write `console.log(this)` in both cases and see.

Comment: I don't understand why is this marked as duplicate. It's not about arrow functions in general, but about two nested arrow functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MDN:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.(...)

Meaning that inside an arrow function the `this` refers to the outter most `this` there is. If you run that in the browser, the `this` is the `window` object.

use `adder.sum` instead of `this.sum`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7kqhwdv/)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. So, in the first case `this.sum` refers to `adder.sum` and the second case `window.sum`? Why is there a difference between the two? You say it's the outer most `this`, but that means the two cases should be identical.

Comment: They are. An arrow function does not bind to any `this`. So when you access `this.adder` you are accessing the first `this` that is in context, probably the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function allows to reach lexical `this`. Which is a context where `adder` is defined, not `adder` itself.

It is expected to work like that:

```
function Foo () {
    // this === foo;
    this.sum = 0;

    const adder = {
        sum: 0,
        add: (numbers) => {
            numbers.forEach(n => {
                // this === foo;
                this.sum += n;
            });
        }
    };

    adder.add([1,2,3]);
}

const foo = new Foo;
```

And

```
const adder = {
    sum: 0,
    add(numbers) { ... }
};
```

is a shortcut for

```
const adder = {
    sum: 0,
    add: function (numbers) { ... }
};
```

so `add` method will have `adder` as `this` when it's called like `adder.add(...)`.

Comment: Of course, here `adder.add` is never called and not available to the outside either.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How come, that in the first case `this.sum` refers to `adder.sum` or is that a false assumption?

Comment: @DávidMolnár In the first case `add` is regular function, which gets dynamic `this`, depending on how it's called. When it's called like `adder.add(...)`, it gets `adder` as `this` because this is the object method were called on. This is how regular functions differ from arrows (explained in dupe questions).

Comment: Thanks for the comparison examples, most useful!